# I want to disable gesture of a particular area of the screen. On a ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose I have a ViewPager which loads a View from XML with Inflate(). I want to disable a particular area of the ViewPager so that when dragging is done on this area the ViewPager will simply not do the job. 
Is this possible somehow ? I don't figure out how to achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to do this on a section of a view, or for a single View?  That is, are you required to only disable part of a `View`'s gesture capabilities?

Comment: I wanna to disable the drag gesture for a part of a view in sense that the Viewpager will not work if I drag on a particular area but the Views (Controls like seekbar) will continue to accept gesture and to handle it. Yes I load in the ViewPager a complete View with many other views.

Comment: You could just overload the `onGestureListener` for the View you are looking at and only implement the Gestures you would like to use :)

Comment: Ok..But the Gesture for the seekbar and for the Viewpager I think are the same ?